# Retrieve Attributes of Mobile Push Locations

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, geolocation

I was trying to use Mobile Push API to create Locations in Marketing Cloud. But I didn't understand how to use Location **Attributes** to pass Location-based parameters to the message context and/or application.

Here is the payload to create a Location in Marketing Cloud :

```
 {
      "name": "Location A",
      "location": "Main Location on Elm Street",
      "description": "Location at 123 Elm St, Nowhere, CA 00000",
      "center": {
        "latitude": 30.750362,
        "longitude": -95.374712
      },
      "radius": 50,
      "attributes": [
        {
          "attribute": "Address 1",
          "value": "123 Elm St"
        },
        {
          "attribute": "City",
          "value": "Nowhere"
        },
        {
          "attribute": "State",
          "value": "CA"
        },
        {
          "attribute": "Zip",
          "value": "00000"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Then in Mobile Push, a geofencing message is created and linked to the above location.

1. Can I use these Attributes to personnalize this Geofencing message ?
2. If not, can I fetch these attributes within the app when the geofencing message is displayed in the app?
3. If not, can I just have the locationID when the geofencing message is displayed in the app? Then I can retrieve those attributes by calling https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getSpecificLocation.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. No, you won't be able to use these attributes for personalization. All the personalization variables can be viewed here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_available_personalization_strings.htm&type=5
2. I don't know if there is an event handler you can subscribe to in order to achieve that. Fetching itself would require some reference between which location triggered the message and then retrieving these details via API through the call you refer to in your question 3.

Comment: Thank you Vlad for your insights. I will ask the support about the availability of an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find some documentation on the JB4A-SDK that allows to retrieve Location Attributes in App using the SDK http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/javadocs/com/salesforce/marketingcloud/messages/RegionMessageManager.RegionTransitionEventListener.html